# Angular 5, execute new function if the first function works

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I would like to launch a new request if this function in relation with my services works, how to proceed? Thank you

**test.component.ts**

```
destroyUnicorn(item){
    this.itemService.updateUnicorn( {
        statut: "destroyed",
        id: item.id
    });
}
```

**item.service.ts**

```
updateUnicorn(item) {
    this.itemDoc = this.afs.doc("unicorns/${item.id}");
    this.itemDoc.update(item)   <------ FireStore request
    .then(function() {})
    .catch(function() {});
}
```

**Global idea :**

-- 1 ° In my template, I click on a button who execute the **function deleteUnicorn** of **my component**.

--- 2 ° The **deleteUnicorn function** sends the parameters to the **updateUnicorn function** in **my services**, which sends a request to Firestore to modify the content in the database.

-- 3 ° I would like, when the function is finished and works, to be able to execute a new function which will modify the user's money in another table of the database.

Comment: This is unclear, can you please elaborate more on this? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Yes of course.
**-- 1 ° --** In my template I click on a button who execute the function **deleteUnicorn** of my **component**.
**--- 2 ° --** The **deleteUnicorn** function sends the parameters to the **updateUnicorn** function in my **services** , which sends a request to Firestore to modify its contents in the database.

**-- 3 ° --** I would like, when the function is finished and works, to be able to execute a new function which will modify the user's money in another table of the database.

Comment: Are you using `AngularFire2` to perform the firestore operation?

Comment: @Chybie yes it is, i use AngularFire2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain promises. Change updateUnicorn() method in order to return a [resolved promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and then add your desired functionality:

```
destroyUnicorn(item){
    this.itemService.updateUnicorn( {
        statut: "destroyed",
        id: item.id
    })
    .then(function(something) {
         // This will execute if updateUnicorn resolves.
    });
}
```

And in your updateUnicorn method:

```
updateUnicorn(item) {
    this.itemDoc = this.afs.doc("unicorns/${item.id}");
    this.itemDoc.update(item)   <------ FireStore request
    .then(function(something) {
          return Promise.resolve(something);
    })
    .catch(function() {});
}
```

Also, if you don't need to use the response of the itemDoc.update() method, you could simply update the function like this:

```
updateUnicorn(item) {
    this.itemDoc = this.afs.doc("unicorns/${item.id}");
    return this.itemDoc.update(item);
}
```

And the destroyUnicorn() will remain the same.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. I discover promises thank you.
One question: Is it possible to use observable for this situation too ?

Comment: Hi. Glad to help. Honestly I can't remember if you could. I believe you need to do observable().toPromise()